# Problem passing PDO::PARAM_INT using array of insert values

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a problem where PDO encapsulates int values using quotes and subsequently makes queries fail.

This is the code (using a wrapper function)

```
$newest = query("SELECT id, body, upvotes, downvotes 
                FROM suggestions ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT :min, :max",
    array(
        ':min' => $min,
        ':max' => $max
    )
);
```

And this is the resulting bad query which causes an error (notice the quotes around the `LIMIT` values)

```
SELECT id, body, upvotes, downvotes FROM suggestions ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT '0' , '50'
```

I'm passing an array of values:

```
array(
    ':min' => $min,
    ':max' => $max
)
```

They're both INTs, and from what I read on the internet PDO should automatically find that out and use `PDO::PARAM_INT` when binding them. The problem is it doesn't actually do that, and since my only way to pass them is through an array I'd like to ask if there's a way to force them to be `PDO::PARAM_INT` without having to use `bindParam()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: also why your only way is with array?

Comment: It's because I'm using a wrapper function, and that wrapper function only allows arrays

Comment: is there a problem for you if you use only for this time standard PDO class? (tho it's not the best idea)

Comment: I don't want to clutter up the code if there's a better solution.

Comment: Are `$min` and `$max` explicitly set to integers in PHP or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a wrapper and you cannot use bindParam then you can do :

```
$min=(int)$min;
$max=(int)$max;
query("SELECT id, body, upvotes, downvotes 
                FROM suggestions ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT $min, $max");
```

This is not the best idea. If you want to keep standards you should improve your wrapper to handle such cases.

Like add a 3rd param in your wrapper

```
function query($q,$paramArray,$bindParamArray) {}
```

So you can effectively use bindParam too

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the error but, now the query returns an empty result. This is strange because executing the same query from PHPMyAdmin gives a valid (not empty result).
Is there a way to see the query that ended up being executed using PDO?

Comment: Nevermind! It was just a small problem on my side. Replacing the values directly into the string worked fine. Thank you very much.